# Cordova Phonegap and Google Maps: Whitelisting not working

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova

I developed an app for Android and now converted it for iOS. The config.xml holds the

```
<access origin="*" />
```

tag. If I comment in the js-link to google maps API, the whole app is blocked as there were an javascript error. If I comment it out, everything is working like a charm but the map of course...

Code in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I use Phonegap/Cordova 3.4.0 on iOS 7.1

Can you provide me with some ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance,

Ingmar

Comment: which config.xml you set?

Comment: hi, every config.xml I could find is set to the same options

Comment: Maybe I should say that in js file I work excessive with an external server url and it works perfect. Only thing is Google maps that gets all to stop working.

Comment: Have you looked at console logs or maybe tried to debug using weinre?

Comment: Sorry a thousand times, I got it to work now. Don't know why but while debugging with weinre I commented in the google-maps-js and it worked... Thnx. for your kindness and help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your Google Map API v3...

Here is the link[1]..

link[1] : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Hope will help you